# How can I use regular expression to caught up urls in angularjs mocks?

Tags: angularjs, angular-mock, ngmocke2e

I need to do something like that

```
  $httpBackend.whenGET('http://url:port/whatever').passThrough();
```

Till now, all the requests I were using were with this pattern

```
  $httpBackend.whenGET('myroute/whatever.html').passThrough();
```

However, I suppose I have to use now a regex starting with /regex/ but I have no idea how to caught up urls

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use regex or a function:

Try this:

```
$httpBackend.when("GET", /\/(.*)/)
```

or

```
$httpBackend.when("GET", function(url) {
    return true
})
```